# Scipy and pulp which will be better if using cplex solver

Tags: optimization, scipy, cplex, operation, pulp

Which among python libraries like pulp and Scipy , has the capability to work with Cplex solver .If we have huge constraints and datasets for optimisation in supply chain .

Comment: The former can use cplex, the latter cannot. But you probably should use the python-library coming with cplex itself (there are 2 imho) if you really target *scalability* (or not use python at all).

Comment: What is a "huge constraint"? Never heard of that concept.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen by huge i meant ..if there are constraint in more number .as we have in any real problems

Answer (score 1):

PuLP is explicitly designed to model (and solve) LPs and it has bindings to use CPLEX under the hood.

You can also use Scipy with CPLEX, just not directly: you can organize your data in scipy and when it comes to creating constraints you can construct them from the data stored in scipy data structures.